# Object defined but when accessing a property returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a really weird issue, can someone explain please.
In my controller, when I am logging an object

```
console.log($rootScope.authUser)
```

it returns:

[image]

where messages is an array of objects. When I am trying to access one of the properties though:

```
console.log($rootScope.authUser.messages)
```

I am getting an empty array - different results! How is this possible 0.o

Comment: Are you sure that `messages` is populated?

Comment: Are you able to see any value for `messages` array in console??

Comment: Are you able to see the contents of messages in console.log($rootScope.authUser)?

Comment: from the output it is clear that the message does not have value. So accessing that property will return null

Comment: @mate.gwozdz do you have values in the messages array as currently it is not visible. Can you post this object in the question? ofcourse after removing other sensitive data.

Comment: Messages is populated, I am 110% sure

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
console.log(angular.copy($rootScope.authUser))
```

It seems that console.log prints the complete object reference, and at the time you look at it, it has already changed. If you make a copy, the copy will not be changed further and you got the "real" output at that time.